# Using :data attribute as a selector to filter elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am trying to use a custom data attribute to filter things via dropdown selections. I can't seem to get the selector to work correctly, and was just wondering if that is actually possible. Currently looking at https://api.jqueryui.com/data-selector/ but I can't seem to get it to work.

My HTML:

```
    <div class="item-filter">
            <form>
                <select id="item-filter-select">
                  <option value="all" id="all">Show All</option>
                  <option value="clothes" id="clothes">Clothing</option>
                  <option value="jewelry" id="jewelry">Jewelry</option>
                  <option value="misc" id="misc">Miscellaneous</option>
                </select>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="item-display" id="item-display">

            <div class="item clothes" id="item-clothes" data-type="clothes" data-name="Sweater01" data-price="15">
                <span>Clothes</span><br>
                <a href="#" class="add-item" id="item01">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>

            <div class="item jewelry" id="item-jewelry" data-type="jewelry" data-name="Necklace01" data-price="5">
                <span>Jewelry</span><br>
                <a href="#" class="add-item" id="item02">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>

            <div class="item misc" id="item-misc" data-type="misc" data-name="PhoneCase01" data-price="10">
                <span>Misc</span><br>
                <a href="#" class="add-item" id="item03">Add to Cart</a>
            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
```

My JS:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
    // Handler for .ready() called.


$('#item-filter-select').change(function() {

    var clothes = $( "div:data(type, clothes)" );

    if($(this).val() === 'clothes'){
        clothes.hide();
        console.log("You selected clothes");
    }
    else if($(this).val() === 'jewelry'){
        console.log("You selected jewelry");
    }
    else if($(this).val() === 'misc'){
        console.log("You selected miscellaneous");
    } 
    else {
        console.log("You are showing all");
    }
});

});
```

I just want to hide the elements associated to the data type "selected" (I will eventually use the :not selector to hide elements that don't match) but for now I just need to get the selectors to work properly. Thank you for any help!

Comment: *"The expression `$( "div:data(foo)")` matches a `<div>` if it has data stored via `.data( "foo", value )`."* Since you haven't stored the data this way, that might be the reason it does not work. I'm not sure when/how exactly jQuery puts the `data-*` attributes into `.data`. If you just care about the values of the data *attributes*, you can use a simple attribute selector.

Comment: You can use `var clothes = $( "div[data-type]" );`

Comment: *"I just want to hide the elements associated to the data type selected"* - [is this what you mean?](http://jsfiddle.net/bEJs7/1/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the selects value directly to target the elements with the correct data attribute

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#item-filter-select').on('change', function () {
        if (this.value == 'all') {
            $('.item').show();
        }else{
            var elems = $('.item[data-type="'+this.value+'"]');
            $('.item').not(elems).hide();
            elems.show();
        }
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ZjKnw/)

or a shorter version of the above

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#item-filter-select').on('change', function () {
        var elems = this.value == 'all' ? $('.item') : $('.item[data-type="'+this.value+'"]');
        $('.item').not(elems.show()).hide();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ZjKnw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like so:

```
$('#item-filter-select').change(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();

   var $selected= $('div').filter(function() { 
       return $(this).data("type") == value;
   });

   $('div').show();
   $selected.hide();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZjKnw/8/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called.

    $('#item-filter-select').change(function() {

        var clothes = $( 'div[data-type="clothes"]' ),
            value = this.value;

        if(value === 'clothes'){
            clothes.hide();
            console.log("You selected clothes");
        }
        else if(value === 'jewelry'){
            console.log("You selected jewelry");
        }
        else if(value === 'misc'){
            console.log("You selected miscellaneous");
        } 
        else {
            console.log("You are showing all");
        }
    });

});
```

But since you have a a class with the same value you could use that..

```
var value = this.value,
    clothes = $( '.clothes' );
```

Or to select based on the selection of the user

```
var value = this.value,
    selection = $( '.'+value );
```

Or to hide all but the selection

```
var value = this.value,
    all = $( '.item' ),
    selected = all.filter('.' + value);
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/S8UYy/
(*shows selected and hides the rest*)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`not`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector and `data-attribute` selector to hide all the elements that not match the selected filter attribute; remember to previously display them all.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#item-filter-select').change(function () {
        $("#item-display div").show();
        if ($(this).val() === 'all') return
        $("#item-display div:not([data-type='" + $(this).val() + "'])").hide();
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/ff8kG/