# Selectbox Laravel select onChange

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I would like to filter some results depending on my selectbox `poule_id` in Laravel. For example, if I select `poule_id = 1`, it should display (on click) all teams that are in the `poule_id = 1`.

Anyone knows a good practice or a quick tutorial to achieve that? I would like to use jQuery for this.

Currently, I have:

> Route::get('search/equipes' , 'CompetitionController@searchEquipes');

My controller :

```
public function searchEquipes(Request $request)
    {
        $equipes = [];

        if($request->has('poule_id')){
            $equipes = EquipePoule::where('poule_id',$request->poule_id)
                ->get();
        }


        return response()->json(['equipes' => $equipes]);
    }



 <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_2">
    <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">


 <select id="poule">
@foreach($select_poules as $select_poule)
<option value="{{$select_poule->id}}">{{$select_poule->lb_poule}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
        </div>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Club</th>
                    <th>Nom de l'équipe</th>
                    <th>Bonus(+/-)</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($equipes as $equipe)
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{!! route('club.show', $equipe->equipe->structure->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->structure->nom_structure}}</a></td>
                    <td><a href="{!! route('equipe.show', $equipe->equipe->id) !!}">{{$equipe->equipe->lb_equipe}}</a></td>
                    <td>{!! Form::text('nb_bonus') !!}</td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on('change', '#poule', function() {

            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "json",
                url : '/search/equipes',
                data : {poule_id : $('#poule').val()},
                success:function(data){

                    $('table tbody').empty().append(data.equipes);

                },
                timeout:10000
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: You are looking for jquery AJAX + Laravel, you have a lot of how to on internet.

Comment: Checkout https://isotope.metafizzy.co

Comment: i will check that thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your javascript file:

```
$(document).on('change', '#poule', function (e) {

                    $.ajaxSetup({
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        }
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: "json",
                        url : '/equipes/search',
                        data : {poule_id : $('#poule').val()},
                        success:function(data){

                        $('table tbody').empty(); 
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.equipes.length; i++){
                           $('table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+data.equipes[i].lb_equipe+'</td></‌​tr>')
                          }

                        },
                        timeout:10000
                    });

            });
```

You should add an id to your select.

In your equipesController define a method 'search', and in your routes add /equipes/search/ route

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {

        $equipes = [];

        if($request->has('poule_id')){
            $equipes = DB::table("equipes")
                ->where('poule_id',$request->poule_id)
                ->get();
        }

        return response()->json(['equipes' => $equipes]);

    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer !!!!! i will test this when i get back home. What do you mean by " you should add an id to your select " ? i need to make a select balise ? <select></select> and put a foreach inside ?

Comment: You just need to add an id to select (e.g. <select id="poule"></select>) so the $(document).on('change', '#poule', function (e) {}); to work. And the append from success response should be different from my example. Something like this: `$('table tbody').empty();` `for (var i = 0; i < data.equipes.length; i++){$('table tbody').append('<tr><td>'+data.equipes[i].lb_equipe+'</td></tr>')}`

Comment: i tried i get a javascript error in the console something like : getPreventDefault() is not working anymore

Comment: it was a script link problem now it's fixed ! i try to select values but now i get in the console : GET 
XHR 
mydomain.com/search/equipes [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 35 ms]

Comment: You defined correctly the route in the routes file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144864/discussion-between-ambrooo-and-mathieu-mourareau).

Answer (score 0):

You can do through 2 ways:

1. Fetch all items and then filter them with jQuery, check  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22699072/using-data-attribute-as-a-selector-to-filter-elements)  question. If the number of items is high I would recommend you the second way.
2. Make a request when is selected a item with AJAX. by this way you can pass the filter with a query string in the URL something like "http://example.com/elements?filter=populate_id" and in your controller return all this items and render them with Javascript.

Comment: thanks for your answer ! i would like to perform with AJAX finally ! with ajax it will not reload the page ?

Comment: No, it won't reload. take a look of this basic example https://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/laravel_ajax.htm @MathieuMourareau

Comment: i think so i added my route and controller in the post ! just updated you can see it